# Spring boot 2.x with Camel 2.25 : Spring specific endpoints not working

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, camel-rest

I have a project with spring-boot 2.x and camel 2.25. It has different camel routes along with few REST consumer routes. Everything is good till this point.

Now I added few normal spring-boot @RestController classes with some endpoints. But these are not working (throwing 404).

When I investigated I found, that **every request is coming to CamelServlet which is totally unaware of spring based normal @RestController endpoints** (but knows only Camel REST consumer route endpoints). Hence throwing this error for only @RestController endpoints whereas Camel REST endpoints are still working.

Below is my configuration,

```
spring:
 application:
  name: gateway
 main:
  web-application-type: SERVLET 


server:
 servlet:
  context-path: /gateway
 port: 8080

camel:
 springboot:
  name: gateway
 component:
  servlet:
   mapping:
    enabled: true
    context-path: /*
  mail:
   basic-property-binding: true
```

Below is my POM

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-mail-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer by Bhushan, was appropriate in this context, but in order to wrap up the conversation, I want to point out one more option to integrate camel routes with non-camel applications as mentioned by @Clause Ibsen in a blog (I lost the link). For any non camel application, we can use FluentProducerTemplate from Camel, that can be autowired using EndpointInject annotation anywhere in say Spring Rest controller class and can be used to send camel exchange to any camel endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of you set **context-path: /*** pattern means camel is going intercept(because this path is register with camel) it, before spring servlet dispatcher gonna handle it, so if you want to handle **@Restcontroller** then you need to define a separate context path for camel, example: **context-path: camel-api/*** pattern, now camel will register **camel-api** base route, and if the pattern is different from **camel-api** URL, it will handle by spring-boot

```
@Bean
ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
    ServletRegistrationBean servlet = new ServletRegistrationBean
      (new CamelHttpTransportServlet(), "camel-api/*");
    servlet.setName("CamelServlet");
    return servlet;
}
```

or configure using properties.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its really helpful. But do we really have any way to configure this two different url (say camel-api/* and others) using configuration properties? I reason I am asking is, being in Spring-boot 2.x environment, I have not configured any Servlet bean explicitely.

Comment: ```camel:
 springboot:
  name: gateway
 component:
  servlet:
   mapping:
    enabled: true
    context-path: camel-api/*```
you can set you path according to your path format pattern here, another then this pattern will autoregister with boot rest controller.
can configure multiple relative path to register with camel
```new ServletRegistrationBean(CamelHttpTransportServlet(), "camel-api/*", "anotherpattern/*");```
I am not sure about how you will achieve it with properties as I didn't find properties auto-configure cls, you can find that cls and figureout property type for it.

Comment: also my suggestion is if you are already using camel API component then stay with it, instead of also integrating @RestController.